# Freezing and Thawing arrays in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm working on a project involving reading and writing from an array in Haskell. I want to store the array in an immutable array type (because I want to avoid mutability as much as possible), so I'm working with the `freeze` and `thaw` functions for [MArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#t%3AMArray)s. I am confused about how I am supposed to use these functions though. This is what I have (that does not compile):

```
modifyBoard bd = freeze mbd 
where 
    t = view falling st
    ps = extractLocs t
    mbd = runSTArray $ do
     a <- thaw bd
     mapM_ (\xy -> writeArray mbd xy (Filled t)) ps
     return a
```

Should I not be using arrays this way or how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the types of `freeze` and `thaw`? Those kind of give a way why this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I know that freeze gives me back an array wrapped in a monad.

Comment: The point is really that `runSTArrray` already gives you back a frozen array. You can't freeze an immutable array.

Comment: Oh, okay that's what I was asking. Thank you. Do you know why the mapM would be wrong?

Comment: "Reading and writing from an array" is fundamentally at odds with "immutable array". I claim that you do _not_ want an immutable array, and your "thaw, mutate, and then freeze again" implementation -- which, by the way, is almost certain to cause problems -- agrees with me.

Comment: Im modifying the array infrequently relative to how often I read from the array. Shouldn't I prefer immutability to mutability whenever I can make that choice?

Comment: @KiraGhandhi If you're not doing frequent modifications, why do you need an array at all?

Comment: Because I'm doing frequent reads. I don't _need_ an array, but it's the data structure I thought would best fit (mostly because it can index on tuples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work with a couple of changes:

1.) Modify your thawed `a` instead of the unthawed `bd`.

2.) No no need to re-freeze after `runSTArray`. The result you return is already frozen.

```
modifyBoard bd = mbd 
    where 
        t = view falling st
        ps = extractLocs t
        mbd = runSTArray $ do
            a <- thaw bd
            mapM_ (\xy -> writeArray a xy (Filled t)) ps
            return a
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I ended up with.

Answer (score 2):

jhickner's answer is correct, but it also seems like you've simply reinvented [`(//)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#v:-47--47-) (which under the hood is implemented very much like how you've written it):

```
modifyBoard bd = bd // map (\xy -> (xy, Filled t)) ps
    where t = ...
          ps = ...
```